# Unexpected '%' appearing in console

Tags: c, console, printf

I'm working through the K&R C programming book, and I just completed exercise 1-13 where you print a histogram of the lengths of words that are input. My horizontal histogram is fine, but my vertical histogram has a '%' sign appearing at the end of it, and I can't figure out why that keeps happening. Here is the loop that I think is causing the issue:

```
for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    printf("%-4d", i + 1);
}
```

If the array_length is 7, I will have a '%' sign after the 7th position like this:

```
                |           
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
|   |   |       |   |       
|   |   |   |   |   |       
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   %
```

If I remove this loop, the vertical bars print fine, I just don't get the numbering below each of them.

What is going on here? As far as I can guess, the printf is running one extra time with garbage data in 'i', but I can't figure out why or how this is happening.

I'm compiling with gcc on Ubuntu, if that makes any difference.

Here is the complete code for your reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000

int main() {

  int c, current_word_length, state, i, j, current_word, largest, array_length, top;
  int word_lengths[ARRAY_SIZE];

  current_word_length = current_word = largest = 0;
  state = OUT;

  for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    word_lengths[i] = 0;
  }

  printf("Enter up to 1000 words and this program will calculate their length.\n");
  printf("Please enter a newline, tab, or space before the last word entered, then EOF to print summary.\n\n");

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
      if (state == IN) {
        word_lengths[current_word++] = current_word_length;
        if (current_word_length > largest) {
          largest = current_word_length;
        }
        current_word_length = 0;
        state = OUT;
      }
    } else {
      state = IN;
      current_word_length++;
    }

  }

  array_length = current_word;

  printf("\nWord Lengths Histogram Horizontal:\n\n");

  for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    printf("%-4d: ", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < word_lengths[i]; j++) {
      printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\nWord Lengths Histogram Vertical:\n\n");

  top = largest;

  while (top > 0) {

    for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
      if (word_lengths[i] >= top) {
        printf("%-4c", '|');
      } else {
        printf("%-4c", ' ');
      }
    }

    printf("\n");

    top--;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    printf("%-4d", i + 1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is what I expect to occur using this input string "Bacon ipsum dolor amet frankfurter landjaeger ham":

```
Enter up to 1000 words and this program will calculate their length.
Please enter a newline, tab, or space before the last word entered, then EOF to print summary.

Bacon ipsum dolor amet frankfurter landjaeger ham

Word Lengths Histogram Horizontal:

1   : =====
2   : =====
3   : =====
4   : ====
5   : ===========
6   : ==========
7   : ===

Word Lengths Histogram Vertical:

                |           
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
                |   |       
|   |   |       |   |       
|   |   |   |   |   |       
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: Are you sure that % isn't just your shell prompt ? Add a `printf("\n");` or `puts(""); ` after your loop (right before `return 0;`)

Comment: OK, that fixed it! So, I'm still learning a lot about how the shell works, can you explain to me what happened or point me to a resource that does?

Comment: Well, you printed out the numbers 1 to 7, and then your program ended. So the shell starts off where you stopped printing. By printing a newline before your program ends, the shell starts whatever it's doing at a newly fresh line, instead of right  after the last number 7.

Comment: I ran your program and entered one string of each length 1 to 9 but not in sequence. It printed no rogue `%` but the histogram was fantasy. 3 of length 1, 5 of length 2 and so on. Time to get the debugger out.

Comment: @WeatherVane the numbers are not the lengths, but the word number that was entered. I'll try doing a version based on word lengths next, I may have misunderstood the assignment!

Comment: Oh, I see: the "histogram" simply gives the length of the string for each entry. One histogram bar for each entry. Well, that's not really what a histogram should do.

Comment: Even with the exact entries: cannot replicate the `%`

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm using oh-my-zsh, and I think it is an zsh + oh-my-zsh issue, as stated here http://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows

Comment: If the `%` prompt means you are running as `root`, you are playing with fire.  Any mistakes made as `root` can be dramatically problematic where the same mistake made as an ordinary user would be far less serious.  Don't do development work as `root`; it simply isn't safe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not running as root, and have learned that lesson the hard way unfortunately!

Comment: That's why there's an "If" at the start of my comment.  Once upon a while ago, `%` was a fairly reliable indicator that you were working as `root` with a C shell.  These days, it isn't as reliable an indicator.  I'm sorry you had to learn the hard way, but better now than when you do serious damage to a production-ready machine.  I won't bore you with my baptism-by-fire story.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as pointed out by nos and chqrlie in the comments, I need to add a newline at the end of my program so that the shell prompt will appear on a newline AFTER the program has finished running.

Adding the putchar() call at the end of main() fixed my issue:

```
  for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    printf("%-4d", i + 1);
  }

  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: You can also use `putchar('\n');` to output a newline.  It has less overhead than `printf("\n");`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree on principle, but modern compilers generate the same code for `printf("\n");`, `puts("");` and `fputchar('\n');`

Comment: It is not per se a shell issue, it is always better for programs to finish their output with a newline, as the unix shells usually do not print one before the prompt. In your case, the shell prompt is `% ` and it appears right after your programs output. Adding the `putchar()` makes the shell prompt appear at the beginning of the next line.